# Foreach noop hides all elements in mocked Dbset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, entity-framework-6

I'm writing unit tests at my application that uses EntityFramework, and Moq for unit tests. While testing a "GetAll" scenario, I found that although I mocked a set of 3 items, none were returning. I whittled the code down to find that a foreach execution cleared my DbSet. What causes this, and how can I fix it?

```
IQueryable<Item> items = new List<Item>() {
    new Item()
 }.AsQueryable();

Mock<DbSet<Item>> mockItemDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Item>>();
mockItemDbSet.As<IQueryable<Item>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(items.Provider);
mockItemDbSet.As<IQueryable<Item>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(items.Expression);
mockItemDbSet.As<IQueryable<Item>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(items.ElementType);
mockItemDbSet.As<IQueryable<Item>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(items.GetEnumerator());
DbSet<Item> itemDbSet = mockItemDbSet.Object;

CompanyContext context = Mock.Of<CompanyContext>(c =>
    c.Items == mockItemDbSet.Object
);

//itemDbSet has a single item
foreach (var item in context.Items) {}
//itemDbSet is empty
```

Edit: A bit more information, to be more specific about itemDbSet having a single item and then being empty. Before the foreach, itemDbSet.Count() is 1, and itemDbSet.ToArray().Count() is 1. That makes sense, of course. After the foreach, itemDbSet.Count() is 1, and itemDbSet.ToArray().Count() is 0. Where is the magician performing this magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checking the Items count once, the enumerator is at the end and needs resetting. Change the setup to this to reset the enumerator.

```
        mockItemDbSet.As<IQueryable<Item>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() =>
        {
            var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
            enumerator.Reset();
            return enumerator;
        });
```

Comment: Oh, awesome! Yep, replacing the GetEnumerator setup with what you've provided keeps the DbSet from being "empty". That also shines some light on Visual Studio mentioning "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable."

Beautiful, thanks so much.

Comment: Dear god, I just spent 2 hours trying to mock the first method, thinking it was that, then I found this. Thanks for unruining my day! Wonder if this is really obvious, since it doesn't have more points :o